# Table cells numbers

Tags: tables, numbers

I'm designing a platform for the stock market where I have multiple tables and all the cells have numbers.

I don´t have enough space because I have a lot of cells and the maximum number that can appear in each cell is 99,000,000,000. Now this would make the cell size huge and the scenario of such a big number appearing is rare.

**What would be a good average cell size? Any best practices?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Display of Tables: Table Cells with Must-See Values](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84593/data-display-of-tables-table-cells-with-must-see-values)

Comment: What's everybody else do? Have you done a competitive audit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some form of **metric prefix for huge numbers**. For example, instead of "99,000,000,000" you can use "$99B", and on hover to show the full number.

```
1,000 = 1k

1,000,000 = 1m

1,000,000,000 = 1B 

1,000,000,000,000 = 1T
```

The financial metric prefixes are taken from [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149190/what-is-the-correct-abbreviation-for-millions-billions-and-trillions-in-a-finan).